# What are you supposed to do with oauth2 confirmation redirects?

Tags: oauth-2.0

If I'm integrating authentication from a third party service into my app, such as github or slack for example, when a user goes to sign up on my app and successfully authenticates with the third party service, what does the data look like that I will receive?

Specifically, if this is a user's second or third time signing in, and they've already signed up before, how do I know they're already signed up? What data do I need to store in my database to know who they are?

Are there common maintenance or upkeep I need to perform on the data about a user's identity? Does it go stale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you receive depends on the response_type and scope parameters of the request uri you are constructing when contacting the third party services. The id_token received is always a JSON Web Token (JWT).

When you request the "openid" scope, the id_token will have "iss", "sub" claims as part of the token payload. These two claims uniquely identify the user by who the provider is and the unique id for that user in that provider. The combination of these two values can be saved in your database to identify if the user is already signed up or not.

When you use a third party provider and save just the bare minimum information (iss, sub), then you do not have to keep up with any information. This would be a nice approach when you don't want to deal with any maintenance. If you need user profile related information you could request the "profile" scope as part of your request which will have more information about the user.

Thank you,
Soma.